# No first name in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

With Biblatex, how to print the author name, in the bibliography, without their first name?

I get

```
Newton, I., G. W. Leibniz, and L. Euler (1600). Infinitesimal Analysis.
```

But I want

```
Newton, Leibniz and Euler (1600). Infinitesimal Analysis.
```

From

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = authoryear-comp,
    maxcitenames = 2,
    maxbibnames = 5,
    sorting = nyt,
    dashed=false,
    uniquename = false,
    uniquelist = false
]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}

    @book{
        newton,
        title = {Infinitesimal Analysis},
        author = {Newton, I. and Leibniz, G. W. and Euler, L.},
        year = {1600}
    }

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

    \nocite{*}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareNameFormat` to only use the last name. 
The `finalandcomma` only appears if applicable. For example, if `ngerman`  is loaded, not comma is set. You can remove the comma by using package `etoolbox`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = authoryear-comp,
    maxcitenames = 2,
    maxbibnames = 5,
    sorting = nyt,
    dashed=false,
    uniquename = false,
    uniquelist = false
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{
        newton,
        title = {Infinitesimal Analysis},
        author = {Newton, I. and Leibniz, G. W. and Euler, L.},
        year = {1600}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{
\usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}
}

%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\finalnamedelim}{\finalandcomma}{}{}{}%Remove the comma
\begin{document}
\cite{newton,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work for me, maybe because of the change to DeclareNameFormat in 3.3: https://www.texdev.net/2016/03/13/biblatex-a-new-syntax-for-declarenameformat/