# Remove author first name from citations

Tags: biblatex, citing, sharelatex

I'm currently writing my PhD thesis in sharelatex and have come across an issue with my citations. I cannot figure out how to remove the first name of the authors from the citations.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber,firstinits=true,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213425/134144

Comment: You probably have two authors with the same last name or the same author in different spellings. `biblatex` tries to distinguish these different people by adding the first name. See [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864) and [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864) for hints how to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Any news here? Did `uniquename=false` help you?

Comment: Any news here? If `uniquename=false` did not help you, it would be good if you could edit your question to explain why.

Comment: Any news here? Could you get things to work as desired?